# Custom Formula field in record detail page to launch vf page is not working in Lightning Experience

Tags: formula, lightning-experience, url

I have a text formula field on custom object which when clicked have to launch a visualforce page. I want to make it working for both Salesforce classic and Lightning Experience. Now it is working only in Salesforce classic mode.

Here is the formula field definition,

```
HYPERLINK("/apex/MyVFPage?recid="+Id+"&parentRecId="+ParentId+"&parentRecName="+parentname,"Click Link")
```

Any help...

Comment: Try this `HYPERLINK('/apex/MyVFPage?recid='+Id+'&parentRecId='+ParentId+'&parentRecName='+parentname, 'Click Link', '_self')`

Comment: I'm able to resolve this issue by applying the above syntax.

Comment: Then you can accept my answer and close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below syntax. As we need single quote instead of double quotes.

`HYPERLINK('/apex/MyVFPage?recid='+Id+'&parentRecId='+ParentId+'&parentRecName='+parentname, 'Click Link', '_self')`